# Multiple instances of random image rotation

Tags: javascript

I am struggling to work out how to make all instances of images with the id="cover__thumb" rotate randomly through the predefined images.

Currently only the first id="cover__thumbs" will rotate, it has no affect on the other images with the same id.

There won't always be 4 images, sometimes more sometimes less. Is there a solution that works for any image with the this id?

Fiddle

https://jsfiddle.net/bpLdkhg0/

JS

```
function rotateImages()
{
    var thumbImages = new Array( );

    thumbImages[0] = "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/e/eb/Ash_Tree_-_geograph.org.uk_-_590710.jpg";
    thumbImages[1] = "http://cdn.images.express.co.uk/img/dynamic/13/590x/magnolia-tree-630524.jpg";
    thumbImages[2] = "http://cdn.images.express.co.uk/img/dynamic/109/590x/Oak-tree-580618.jpg";

    var image = document.getElementById('thumb__cover');
    var randomImageIndex = Math.floor( Math.random( ) * thumbImages.length );
    image.src = thumbImages[randomImageIndex];
}
window.setInterval(rotateImages, 1000);
```

HTML

```
<img id="thumb__cover" src="http://pic.1fotonin.com//data/wallpapers/121/WDF_1633007.jpg" style="width:150px;">
<img id="thumb__cover" src="http://pic.1fotonin.com//data/wallpapers/121/WDF_1633007.jpg" style="width:150px;">
<img id="thumb__cover" src="http://pic.1fotonin.com//data/wallpapers/121/WDF_1633007.jpg" style="width:150px;">
<img id="thumb__cover" src="http://pic.1fotonin.com//data/wallpapers/121/WDF_1633007.jpg" style="width:150px;">
```

Comment: `id`s should be unique.

Comment: id should be unique on whole page, so use class name instead.

Comment: Ahh yes, that's so obvious once pointed out, I'll change it to getElementsByClassName and see what happens, thanks guys

Comment: By rotate you don't actually mean rotate eh.  I wonder what the correct term should be?

Comment: @James Maybe shuffle would have been a more accurate term. Rotate doesn't really fit at all now you pointed it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `class` attribute if you want to select multiple DOM elements at once:

HTML:

```
<img class="thumb__cover" ... />
```

JS:

```
var images = document.querySelectorAll(".thumb__cover");
```

or

```
var images = document.getElementsByClassName("thumb__cover");
```

Now, images is a `nodeList` that can have any number of elements. To set the `src` attribute for each of them, you'll have to loop through the items in the list:

```
for (var i = 0; i < images.length; i += 1) {
  var image = images[i];
  var randomImageIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * thumbImages.length);

  image.src = thumbImages[randomImageIndex];
}
```

More about node lists: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/NodeList

Comment: I tried this, both ways but it stopped working all together :\ https://jsfiddle.net/bpLdkhg0/1/

Comment: `images` is now a `nodeList`. You need to loop through it to set all of the nodes' in this list `src` attributes. I've edited my answer to show you how.

Comment: Great explanation I can see exactly what you're saying, appreciate it and the link, thank you